# Is it possible to extract amplitude data from an audio file using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I've found a couple libraries that deal with Waveforms in JS so I'm assuming it's possible to directly utilize the data in an audio file, but in my case I don't particularly care about visualizing it. I just want to "extract" certain data.

For example: There is a form control that lets someone upload an audio file (mp3 typically). I want to be able to then show certain statistics about that file like length, average amplitude, lowest amplitude, highest amplitude... etc.

Is this data accessible somehow? I'm hoping there is some way I can have it as an array.

The data doesn't *have* to be from a form input either, if the file needs to be uploaded on a separate page and then saved and loaded into an html `<audio>` tag, that can happen. The important part I'm looking for here is getting the data out of an audio file.

Comment: Look into reading bytes with Javascript. Some information is in the MP3 header. For amplitude you have to decode the MP3 data (compression math) into digital sound (PCM). PCM will also be bytes, so for 16-bit sound you read the value of two bytes at once (repeat by `for` loop until bytes ending). Each value is the amplitude, so from your loop you note the highest and lowest (so far) and only note any new higher/lower amps than already known. By end, you'll know highest and lowest amplitudes.

Comment: @VC.One Thanks! Really helpful direction! If you want to put it as an answer, I'll accept it as it's all I really needed!

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/soundamplitude

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a concrete answer, but [`BaseAudioContext.decodeAudioData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/decodeAudioData), which is a part of ["Web Audio API"](https://wiki.developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API), may help.